# Как решить ошибку отладки?( vector subscript out of range)

Tags: c++, vector, struct

Возможно неправильно что-то сделал с вектором структур, первый раз с таким работаю.`Помогите пожалуйста, если знаете в чём дело)

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
struct money
{
int Rubles, Kopecks;
};

int main()
{
    int n, k,max1, max2, min1, min2;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    cout << "Программа выводит максимальную и минимальную денежную суммы" << endl;
    cout << "Введите количество денежных сумм" << endl;
    cin >> n;
    vector <money> a;
    a.reserve(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << "Введите количество рублей " << i + 1 << "-ой денежной суммы" << endl;
    cin >> a[i].Rubles;
    cout << "Введите количество копеек " << i + 1 << "-ой денежной суммы" << endl;
    cin >> a[i].Kopecks;
    if (a[i].Kopecks >= 100)
    {
        k = a[i].Kopecks / 100;
        a[i].Kopecks -= k * 100;
        a[i].Rubles += k;
    }
}
max1=a[0].Rubles;
max2=a[0].Kopecks;
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
{
    if (a[i].Rubles > max1)
    {
        max1 = a[i].Rubles;
        max2 = a[i].Kopecks;
    }
    if (a[i].Rubles == max1)
        if (a[i].Kopecks > max2)
            max2 = a[i].Kopecks;
}
min1 = a[0].Rubles;
min2 = a[0].Kopecks;
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
{
    if (a[i].Rubles < min1)
    {
        min1 = a[i].Rubles;
        min2 = a[i].Kopecks;
    }
    if (a[i].Rubles == min1)
        if (a[i].Kopecks < min2)
            min2 = a[i].Kopecks;
}
cout << "Максимальная сумма: " << max1 << "рублей " << max2 << "копеек" << endl;
cout << "Минимальная сумма: " << min1 << "рублей " << max2 << "копеек" << endl;
_getch();
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

`vector::reserve` выделяет память на всякий случай, но доступ не разрешает. Нужно использовать `vector::resize`

Answer (score 0):

Лучше напишите то же самое по принципу ООП

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
struct money
{
    int Rubles, Kopecks;
    friend  std::istream&    // чтобы вводить сразу обьект
    operator >>(std::istream& is, money& m)
    {
        is >> m.Rubles >> m.Kopecks;
        int k = m.Kopecks / 100;
        if  ( k ) {
            m.Kopecks -= k * 100;
            m.Rubles += k;
        }
        return is;
    }
    bool operator <(const money& m)   //для сортировки
    {
        if (Rubles == m.Rubles)
            return Kopecks < m.Kopecks;
        return Rubles < m.Rubles;
    }
};


int main()
{   
    int n{};
    cin >> n;
    vector<money> a(n); // сразу создаем вектор размера n
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        cout << "Введите количество рублей  и копеек "
             << i + 1 << "-ой денежной суммы" << endl;
        cin >> a[i];
    }
    sort(a.begin(), a.end());
    money max = a[n - 1], min = a[0];
    cout << "Максимальная сумма: " << max.Rubles << " рублей  " 
         << max.Kopecks  << " копеек" << endl;
    cout << "Минимальная сумма: " << min.Rubles << "рублей "
         << min.Kopecks << "копеек" << endl;    
    return 0;
}
```